# How to store a randomly generated 2-D list from a while loop?

Tags: python

I am unable to store unique 1D list into a 2D list.

I'm having trouble storing multiple randomly generated list into a 2D list. I can generate n number of unique 1D generated lists but when I try to store them in a 2D list, I get the same 1D list generated n number of time.

I've used the append() function on the list but instead get the same 1D list appended multiple times.

I've used the extend() function but it returns a 1D list.

I don't understand why the object is aliased when I'm using the shuffle() function.

```
import random
bd = list(range(10))
rng = random.Random()
rng.shuffle(bd)
d_list = []
number = 0 

while number < 5:
    d_list.append(bd)
    number += 1

print(d_list)
```

I expected the results to be

[[6, 5, 3, 8, 2, 4, 0, 9, 1, 7],[7, 6, 9, 8, 5, 3, 4, 0, 2, 1], [2, 1, 0, 7, 3, 8, 6, 5, 4, 9], [1, 2, 7, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9],**[7, 6, 3, 8, 4, 5, 1, 9, 0, 2]**]

but instead the results are

**[[7, 6, 3, 8, 4, 5, 1, 9, 0, 2], [7, 6, 3, 8, 4, 5, 1, 9, 0, 2], [7, 6, 3, 8, 4, 5, 1, 9, 0, 2], [7, 6, 3, 8, 4, 5, 1, 9, 0, 2], [7, 6, 3, 8, 4, 5, 1, 9, 0, 2]]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your initialization of bd to your loop:

```
import random

d_list = []
number = 0

while number < 5:
    bd = list(range(10))
    rng = random.Random()
    rng.shuffle(bd)
    d_list.append(bd)
    number += 1

print(d_list)
```

Right now, you're shuffling and adding the same list to d_list 5 times. Initializing the list inside the loop means that you're actually creating 5 different lists.

Answer (score 2):

In your code:

```
while number < 5:
    d_list.append(bd). #bd is the same and initialized one time
    number += 1
```

You need to execute the randomizer within the while for you to truly have random lists each time.

Answer (score 1):

To solve your problem, shuffle `bd` at every iteration or use this one-liner to generate the same list:

```
d_list = [random.sample(range(10), 10) for i in range(5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're appending 5 times the same list to an empty list. The result shows exactly that.

If you want a new random list to be generated at every iteration, I would recommend placing the list shuffle inside the loop.

```py
import random

bd = list(range(10))
rng = random.Random()
rng.shuffle(bd)
d_list = []
number = 0 

while number < 5:
    rng.shuffle(bd)
    d_list.append(bd)
    number += 1
```

Note: I owuld also recomment using a `for` loop instead of a `while` [info](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/control-flow-2/python-for-and-while-loops) :

```py
import random

bd = list(range(10))
rng = random.Random()
rng.shuffle(bd)
d_list = []

for range(5):
    rng.shuffle(bd)
    d_list.append(bd)
```